# What is meaning of even (odd) operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, parity, graded-modules, graded-algebras

Let $ V^{\bullet}=\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} V^{i} $ is graded vector space. What is the meaning of even(odd) operator on this graded vector  space? It related to shifts the grading by even(odd) number but I don’t understand it.

Also the the parity of even operator is $0$and,for odd one is $1$.

Comment: Where did you encounter this terminology?